Can one be a Gauḍīya Vaiṣṇava and believe Caitanya Mahāprabhu to not be an avatar?
I've been wondering whether that is allowed in Gauḍīya sampradāya.
Without any disrespect to anyone, if one believes that Caitanya Mahāprabhu was NOT an avatar, and believes him to be a pure bhakta, woud that be allowed by any gurus?
What if one wants to focus entirely on Krishna without the worshipping of Mahāprabhu and his brother or associates as 'gods' but still accept Gauḍīya Vaiṣṇavism?

but then if you don't believe it are you a Gaudiya Vaishnava in the present understood way? I mean there were Gaudiya Vaishnavas before Chaitanya Mahaprabhu, so maybe you will be like them. Also you would be like Vaishnavas and Sri Vaishnavas maybe?

It's impossible to be a Gaudiya Vaishnava without believing in the divinity of Chaitanya Mahaprabhu, it's like being Srivaishnava without believing in the Alvars' or Ramanuja's divinity.

'What if one wants to focus entirely on Krishna without the worshipping of Mahāprabhu and his brother or associates as 'gods' but still accept Gauḍīya Vaiṣṇavism?' Never heard about it. In Bengal, brahmins & other upper-caste followers of Gaudiya Vaishnavas worship Radha-Krishna alongside the Panchatattva. However, lower caste followers, especially 'caste Vaishnavas' (a distinct caste group in Bengali Hindu society whose ancestors had converted from Vajrayana Buddhism to Gaudiya Vaishnavism around 16th century) had a practice of exclusively venerating the Panchatattva.

@HariKumar Śri Vaiṣṇavas do not believe in Rādhārānī worship. I feel that the Acintya-Bheda-Abheda philosophy is the closest to my heart and also the way Kṛṣṇa is worshipped.

@অনু I am fine with accepting some sort of divinity, every Vaiṣṇava is worshippable, especially these mahā-bhāgavatas but still, I don't see them as my Kṛṣṇa, I can't worship them as my Kṛṣṇa :(( I see them as my gurus, I can worship them as my gurus but it still feels weird to have their vigraha and worship them the same as Laddū Gopāla.

@MaySha but aren't there other philosophers like Ramananda Sampradaya? Nimbarka Sampradaya and Vallabacharya Sampradaya?

@HariKumar Rādhāvallabha seems nice, they follow Śuddhadvaita though. I haven't been able to find much information about it.

@MaySha if I may ask why do you have a problem of seeing Chaitanya Mahaprabhu as Shri Krishna

@HariKumar because I've gone through Gauḍīya texts and I don't believe the pramāṇas that prove Caitanya Mahāprabhu was an avatar. I've seen all the references given by Gauḍīya Vaiṣṇavas, them using Upaniṣadas or Bhāgavatam to prove that he's Kṛṣṇa but my heart does not accept it, it seems like a stretch.
Caitanya Caritāmrita is nice but then again, it's a text from the 16-17th century, written by Kavirāja to prove that he's Kṛṣṇa.

@Nandīśvara We could write a scripture about any great mahā-bhāgavata, Prabhupāda for example, declaring him to be the supreme's avatar but would we accept it? Some now claim Svāmīnārāyaṇa to be the source of Kṛṣṇa. Do we accept it?
Things get exaggerated over time, I've seen that myself and anybody can write any scripture according to their understanding and with time, it might even get accepted by the masses.
I don't mean this as a disrespect, I have utmost respect for the ācāryas, but this is something I looked into but cannot accept, unfortunately.

@Nandīśvara We don't really have any authentic records of Mahāprabhu's writings, as they're very few in quantity. The only thing we have is the words by his followers and disciples, who already saw their Guru as God so it's not difficult to see why they'd claim such things. This came up recently, a scholar mentioned how many of the bhakti texts written by the jīva gosvāmī do not find any basis in any of the Vedānta traditions (The concept of tatastha shakti for example, they were made up explicitly without any śastric backing). So that made me wonder how much of it is correct.

I don't mind the knowledge at all. It doesn't matter if it's not in the Vedānta as long as it helps me feel the love for Kṛṣṇa. However, I don't see why it would be important to worship the idols of the gurus as if it's vigraha-avatāra when we know only bhagavān and the top-most devatās/devīs have that power.
Reading about Mahāprabhu's love, just like reading about Mīra Baī or Tukārāma, gives me love for Kṛṣṇa. I do not see how their worship is important to bhakti. I can worship them as great bhaktas, but not as Kṛṣṇa himself as there is only one Kṛṣṇa for me.

@Nandīśvara I understand. I can see their worship in a different mood, that's something I'd be comfortable with but I've seen many ISKCON devotees worship them as Krishna which seemed odd to me. I came to Krishna bhakti independently, and I discovered the other things later so I'm still very much uncomfortable with many things, especially since India is home to a lot of unfounded beliefs and superstitions. But thank you, I see your point. I still cannot accept them as avatars but I can definitely love them as great bhaktas.
